# Find all records that contain a single character followed by a space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all records that contain a middle initial in the following format:

```
N Jones  
S Smith  
T Thompson
```

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM USERS 
WHERE Last_Name LIKE '% %'
```

This query returns

```
JE Smith  
TE Jones
```

I only want to include rows that contain a single character at the beginning of the string followed by a space.

Comment: *"I only want to include rows that contain a single character at the beginning of the string followed by a space."* Then don't use a multi-character wildcard (`%`) use a single character wildcard (`_`).

Comment: Have sample table data and expected result that match, i.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Where users like '_ %'   ., or you can even try Where substring(users,2,1)=' '

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Where substring(users,2,1) = ' ' worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want to include rows that contain a single character at the beginning of the string followed by a space.

Then don't use a multi-character wildcard (%) use a single character wildcard (_).